# How many declined flags are you allowed to have?

Tags: support, flagging

I have $130$ helpful flags right now, $3$ declined, and around $37$ waiting for review. I was wondering, what would happen if a lot of the flags ended up declined? What threshold of missed flags are you allowed to have and what are the consequences of too many missed flags?

Comment: I'm not sure if this question has a well-defined answer, or that one (if it exists) should even be given. The goal should be to focus simply on getting as many good flags; I could see ne'er-do-wells using any such threshold as a way to toe the line without crossing it. (Why someone would do that is another matter, but abuse prevention never hurts.)

Comment: By "missed flags" do you mean flags waiting for review (pending)?  Or something else?

Comment: @hardmath declined flags

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll get warned and eventually flag banned (i.e. you can't flag anymore, but otherwise you can use the site normally). For that to happen, you have to cast a lot of flags (10 or more in the past seven days) *and* a rather high percentage of declined flags in the past seven days: 10% for a warning, and 25% for a ban. Comment flags aren't counted (and neither are disputed flags), just helpful and declined post flags. As soon as the percentage is low enough, you get out of the ban, so a flag ban lasts seven days maximum.

The details are explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/295232) by former Community Manager Shog9.